# html2Canvas vs dom-to-image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

Working on a project and the function below seems to take a great deal of time to process. I've seen html-to-image being talked up as better alternative although html2Canvas is clearly the most popular. Anyone used both and could confirm which one is faster?

````
  function saveVoucher(name) {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#voucher');
    const myPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 1000);
    });
    myPromise.then(() => {
      html2Canvas(canvas, {
        scrollY: -window.scrollY,
        scale: 2,
      }).then((canvas) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsOpen(true);
        let dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 2.0);
        const voucher = new jsPDF({
          unit: 'px',
          format: [185, 240],
        });
        voucher.addImage(dataURL, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 185, 240);
        voucher.save(`${name}.pdf`);
      });
    });
  }```
````

Comment: This is not a question for SO, because _you_ can answer it without anyone's help: write the code for `html-to-image` and then compare them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I understand you saying it's a dumb question after all I'm relatively a newbie with zero reputation but you also have to consider that everyone at some point in their journey may not run test under best possible condition and may need a second/expert opinion.

Comment: Then you _don't_ understand, because it's not a dumb question: it's a perfectly normal question to have, it's just not an appropriate question _for posting on Stackoverflow_.SO is not a general help forum, it's fairly specific, and has rules and guidelines about what's [on topic](/help/on-topic) and what you are expected to do both [before you decide to post, and when you do post](/help/how-to-ask) so, if your question can be answered by you, it's not something you should be posting on SO (at least, not yet. If you run into implementation issues, then _that_  might be the time to post to SO).

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I see what your saying but I want to add that in this case it is an appropriate question for SO. HTML2IMAGE and HTML2CANVAS have different implementation patterns and by faster it could also mean better compatibility. It is a very specific question that compares two programming libraries and in line with SO.

Comment: Even then: no it isn't, because you're effectively asking for opinions. If you want to know how two libraries compare, for your needs, it's on you to simply use both libraries and see which does what you need easiest/fastest/whatever-you-consider-best. No one else can do that benchmarking for you: that's simply part of [your responsibility to research things](/help/how-to-ask) before posting. And if those libraries have different implementation patterns: implement the appropriate pattern for each library because that factors into your decision on which is best.